# Displaying logged user after successful login with services in angular:

Tags: angular

I am trying to show logged user in the header navbar after a successful login but for some reason it refuses to appear in the navbar.

```
app.component.ts(login page)  ->  db-srv-conn.service.ts(service) -> main.component.ts(menu page with navbar)
```

**db-srv-conn.service.ts :**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class DbSrvConnService {
  username=new Subject<any>();
 
 constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
      send_user(value)
      {
        this.username.next(value);
      } 
      get_user():Observable<any>{
        return this.username.asObservable();
      }
}
```

**app.component.ts(login page):**

```
import { DbSrvConnService } from 'src/app/sevices/db-srv-conn.service';

export class AppComponent{
  formGroupLogin:FormGroup;
  constructor(private DbSrvConnService:DbSrvConnService) { }
...
login(){
    if (status==1){
            this.DbSrvConnService.send_user(usrname);
            this.router.navigate(['main']);
          }
}
```

**main.component.ts:**

```
import { DbSrvConnService } from 'src/app/sevices/db-srv-conn.service';
...

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private DbSrvConnService:DbSrvConnService) { 
    this.DbSrvConnService.get_user().subscribe(
  (resultp)=>{
     console.log(resultp);
  } 

)
```

}

But in the console, the following message is displayed instead of the `resultp` value :

```
 ƒ next(value) {
            if (this.closed) {
                throw new _util_ObjectUnsubscribedError__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["ObjectUnsubscribedError"]();
            }
            if (!this.isStopped) {
          …
```

Comment: Can you try to initialize variable username as "BehaviourSubject" instead of "Subject". like this  "username=new BehaviorSubject<any>("");". @mahdi.gh

Comment: error : Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
    
    10   username=new BehaviorSubject<any>();

Comment: What is `usrname` in `this.DbSrvConnService.send_user(usrname)`?

Comment: The value of the username that is sent to the service from login component

Comment: Have you checked that value with the debugger or using the console? It looks like it is not a simple value but an Observable.